# how to call tcpdf file , i am using href header and javascript but not working

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf

The following is not working:

```
echo "<script>
         alert('Vai entrar pdf'); 
         window.location.href='/tcpdf/apqp/riscoponto4F.php?id='+$pid; 
      </script>";
```

I am trying to call the php from `tcpdf` that has the info, it must run without using `href` or `header` (i have more headers in the code) and i am trying with `javascript`

Any ideas?

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: the goal is to create the pdf in the code without a href url or a header